# Best strategy for finding an identical image on server and getting file location

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im building a web application that is a digital asset manager only for image files. 
When an image is uploaded, the file is saved to a folder and a row inserted in an mysql database with a hash that lets me detect image duplicates.

The browser won't let me get the original file location on upload for security reasons. 
The only way i can think of getting the original file location is building a database table (with two columns: location path, difference hash) of **ALL** images on my server, this way i can find the location of any image by matching the hash.
There could be thousands of images on the server... is there be a better way?

Comment: checking a hash against a few thousand rows in a table is not particularly many. If you are worried it will grow beyond what sensible indexing will manage consider using shards and modulos of the hash to divide entries between tables.

Comment: Make sure to create an index for the hash column of your table, and it should be fine. I support MySQL databases with *hundreds of millions* of rows. A few thousand won't be a problem, unless you're using a 20 year old server! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use hashes to check for identical images, they have to be bit-for-bit identical. Similar isn't good enough. You know that. It means you can use lengths.

So, for each image you want to check,  store the length and the hash in your table. Then use a query like this

```
    SELECT image_id, whatever
      FROM image_hash
     WHERE image_hash.length = ??length?? 
       AND image_hash.hash = ??hash?
```

Put this compound index on your `image_hash` table:

```
CREATE INDEX image_hash_match ON image_hash (length, hash);
```

That index first uses the length for a really fast integer lookup, then looks up the hash. This will scale up to very large numbers of images successfully (*very large numbers* = at least hundreds of millions).
Text string lookups of hashes are also reasonably fast, but not as fast as integer lookups.

Comment: actually, now that i've developed some parts, the real problem is building and _maintaining_ the table with all image hashes, because I have to assume that images in the server may be added, deleted or moved.